# Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit

Tags: bug, profile-page, email, error-message

I'm having this error while trying to update my profile. Can anyone please help me figure out, what's the problem.

[image]

Comment: What specifically are you trying to edit?

Comment: I'm trying to edit my Display name.

Comment: Weird, what browser and version are you using?

Comment: IIRC there was another report either here or on MSE with the same error and the user equally surprised. Before we close it, are we sure this isn't a regression of the profile update logic causing to trip a wrong error message?

Comment: In the last case that I saw, the user had another account with the same email address. For GRIZZ, I cannot find another account having the same email address (nor do I see evidence he recently changed this account's email address). So... I don't know what's happened here.

Comment: @CodyGray as they are setting their displayname, that does also change stuff at the developer story end. Maybe the sunsetting of that feature has more impact then they hoped for ....

Comment: I have just ran into the same issue trying to update my profile picture. I was logged in with my Github account but I have also tried adding a few different email addresses and logging in with them. Still get the same error.